# Permission denied in mounted volume on Docker with SELinux

Tags: docker

I've tried to mount a folder using the following docker compose file (partially reproduced, the rest aren't relevant):

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    environment:
      - DEBUG=0
    volumes:
      - /usr/share/nginx/html/assets:/assets:Z
```

However, aside from `cd`-ing into the folder `/assets` in the docker container, I get the following error for other operations in the folder (including `chmod` and `chcon`):

```
ls: cannot open directory '.': Permission denied
```

The folder UID and GID are 0 (i.e. root) and the UID of the bash in docker is also 0.

However, by removing the `Z` flag, the docker container is able to read content off the volume, but not write into it.

Here is the output of `ls -laZ` with the `Z` flag on:

```
drwx------.   2 root root system_u:object_r:container_var_run_t:s0         160 Jan 27 15:33 assets
```

and here is without `Z` flag:

```
drwxr-xr-x.   4 root root unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0      72 Jan 23 09:01 assets
```

It seems that with the Z flag, my group and others permission disappears, but that does not matter because the UID is the same, right?

---

My question is, how can I get write access to the mounted directory in the docker container?